# StaleElementReferenceException in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

```
url="https://www.pla...com"
browser=Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver')
browser.get(url)
components=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.files-new a')
for i in components:
   print(i.get_attribute("href")) 
   browser.get(i.get_attribute("href"))
```

I am collecting links and trying to iterate over them. But in the 2nd loop I get that StaleElementReference error. Shouldn't **find_elements** store and keep links? Any idea to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call browser.get() in your loop, you're now on a new page, so all the "element objects" in your [components] variable are stale.

Solution: Collect all the "href" values from your [components] into a string list before you start your loop. Then, in your loop, read your href's from that list, not from the stale element objects in your [components].

Comment: Thank you Conrad ! It solved my problem ! Pray for you!